# Compare dates with IF

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

Three columns below, I'm attempting to use column C as a formula that checks against a hard coded date.

`8/18/14    12/19/20    formula`

In column C `=IF(AND("10/7/15">=A1,"10/7/15"<=B1),"IN","OUT")`

What I'm looking for is to tell if 10/7/15 is between 8/18/14 & 12/19/20 - I would expect that to come back with a value of IN but it doesn't.... hoping its something simple I'm missing

Comment: Your date format is ambiguous. Is `12/19/20` the 19th December 2020 or 20th of December 2019? Consider using ISO-8061 (`yyyy-MM-dd`) format dates to be unambiguous.

Comment: Updated to use mm/dd/yyyy but still doesn't make a difference in the formula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is you're comparing a date (which translates to a number) to a text string.  It's a crap-shoot as to what Excel will do in this case.  If you compare a date to a date, I believe you will get the desired behavior:

```
=IF(AND(DATE(2015,10,7)>=A1,DATE(2015,10,7)<=B1),"IN","OUT")
```

The `datevalue` function should also work.

Answer (score 0):

If you really have a date in A1, you can try:

```
=IF(AND(VALUE("2015-10-07")>=VALUE(A1),VALUE("2015-10-07")<=VALUE(B1)),"IN","OUT")
```